# Trouble with interpreting a question about polynomial rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

I trying to do problem $9.3.1$ in Dummut & Foote; I think they use some "abuse of notation" that I don't understand.

> Let $R$ be an integral domain with quotient field $F$ and let $p(x)$ be a monic polynomial in $R[x]$. Assume $p(x) = a(x)b(x)$ where $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are monic polynomials in $F[x]$ of smaller degree than $p(x)$. $\color{red}{\text{Prove that if a(x)} \not \in \text{R[x] then R is not a U.F.D.}}$ Deduce that $\mathbb{Z}[2\sqrt2]$ is not a U.F.D.

The part in red is what's confusing me. The reason why I think it's "abuse of notation" is because there is nothing to distinguish $a(x)$ from $b(x)$. So I could see an argument for each of the following interpretations, and I don't know which one is correct:

- Exactly one of $a(x), b(x)$ is not in $R[x]$
- At least one one of $a(x), b(x)$ is not in $R[x]$
- Precisely both of $a(x), b(x)$ are not in $R[x]$

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit for Lord Shark the Unknown:**

Proof that if $(x+a)(x+b) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Since $(x+a)(x+b) = x^2 + (a+b)x + ab$ we know $ab \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a+b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus:

$$a^2+2ab+b^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\implies a^2-2ab +b^2\in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\implies (a-b)^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\implies a-b \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\implies (a+b)(a-b) \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\implies a^2-b^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Now we can also get that $a^2+b^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ using the same trick we used in the first steps. So $(a^2+b^2)-(a^2-b^2) \in \mathbb{Z}$,

$$\implies 2a^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\implies a^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\implies a \in \mathbb{Z}$$

And by a similar argument, $b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Both factors must be in $R[x]$ if the product is, so at least one must not be if the product isn't. It's not an abuse of notation, but it does rely implicitly on the commutativity of multiplication.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks! I can see how going very technical, that would be 100% the correct interpretation. However, I was not sure if that was the case or they were using "abus of notation"; Dummit & Foote sometimes seem to drop certain assumptions which I think they want the reader to infer from the previous paragraph of from the section in general.

Comment: @EthanBolker Could you please elaborate a little on your first sentence? Since $(a_1x+a_0)(b_1x+b_0) = a_1b_1x^2 + x(a_1b_0+a_0b_1) + a_0b_0$, I don't see why we cannot have $a_0, a_1, b_0, b_1$ being non-integer rationals, yet they conspire together to make $a_1b_1, a_0b_0$, and $a_1b_0+a_0b_1$ all integers.

Comment: @Ovi Recall that $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are assumed to be **monic**.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I've edited the question with a proof that if $(x+a)(x+b) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. However, of course this covers just one case, it requires me to prove a couple lemmas which I didn't include, and I know there must be an abstract algebra way to prove it for the general case. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I was just commenting on what I thought the sentence meant, not on whether it was true.